# Download file when logged in ssh ? - Not scp

Tags: ssh, download, scp

this may be a really stupid question - but actually I did not find an answer.
I read a lot about scp, which would serve in my case. But my guess is it should be easier:

I'm already logged into a ssh server and I'm seeking for a command to download a file to my machine. All I found is scp commands which server credentials - those seem to be obsolete in my case. So does something exist like:

```
myserver:~$ [command-in question] filename [optional: target on local machine]
```

Thanks a lot in advance, Wolf

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and note that Stackoverflow is a **programming** Q&A site, not a general computing one. Try https://superuser.com/ instead.